# Copy text file to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried copying text file into Excel through VBA. There are many unwanted rows and strings in the file but I want only specific ones to come under the Excel sheet.

```
Sub Inte()
    Dim j, LastCol As Long
    Dim inval As Variant

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Sheet12.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 7 To LastCol
           If Cells(i, j).Value <> Int(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
               If InStr(1, Cells(i, j).Value, ".0") > 0 Then
                   Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 7) & Cells(i, j)
                   Cells(i, j).ClearContents
               End If

       Next j
    Next i

    'Columns("").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A14", "A21").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

There is no specific pattern that could be followed for creating logic, so after copying all the data from text file into Excel, I started doing coding in Excel based on rows and columns

Now I want some columns data to be appended i.e col7,col8,col9 till a decimal value is reached i.e price column `470.00` (this has to be in seperate column), so all the before columns from column 7 have to be appended with space.

In next row it could be col7,col8 to be appended

Ex : detergent (LIME-A-WAY) 3.8 Lt. is expected but when the text file is read into excel all these values are in seperate columns.

Comment: Is there a Question ?

Comment: ① I indented your code so you can see there is a `End If` missing. This code should throw an exception/error. ② If you declare `Dim j, LastCol As Long` only `LastCol` is declared `As Long` but `j` is declared `As Variant`. You must specify a type for **every** variable in VBA `Dim j As Long, LastCol As Long`. Also you should use `Option Explicit` to make sure you declare **all** your variables. Eg `i`  and `LastRow` are not declared.

Comment: This is only a sub func which is called from main one ,so while copying the actual data , sorry i missed few . So i want a code where it reads all rows from column 7 till a decimal value cell is reached and append all the cells in between to column 7 cell.

Comment: If InStr(1, Cells(i, j).Value, ".0") > 0 Then , this code is not working to check if the cell contains a decimal column , so i want some code ,where it checks the cell value in loop is a decimal or not.

Comment: Please provide proper example data and how the output that you expect would look like. We need a [mcve] to help you properly.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a cell value is a decimal you can use something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsDecimal(ByVal InputValue As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDecimal = IsNumeric(InputValue) And InStr(1, InputValue, Application.DecimalSeparator) > 0
End Function
```

So instead of your 2 `If` statements you only need one:

```
If IsDecimal(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
```

Comment: isDecimal logic is not working :( .. and i want this logic to Do Until loop where in column 7 all the right column values have to be appended till the decimal value column is reached